# Scraping Data using BS4 gives me unexpected results

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I don't want to annoy you with my very basic questions, but I am stuck and I hope you can help me.
I've done tutorials and watched many videos but i can't figure out what i am doing wrong.
I want to scrape data from this table: https://www.youpriboo.com/vorher_102_main_nat.php?action=show&liga=2.BL

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_URL = 'https://www.youpriboo.com/vorher_102_main_nat.php?action=show&liga='
liga = '2.BL'
URL = base_URL + liga

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36:'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for name in soup.find_all("td", class_="hac"):
    name1 = name.parent.find_all('td')[1] # team1 
    name2 = name.parent.find_all('td')[2] # team2
    wahr1 = name.parent.find_all('td')[6] # wahr1
    print(name1.get_text() +' '+ name2.get_text()+' '+ wahr1.get_text())
```

The Problem is that it gives me the data 3 times and there are 3 numbers listed between the games.

The expected result would look like this:

```
Armina Bielefeld VfB Stuttgart 34,43
SV Wehen Wiesbaden VfL Osnabrück 34,51
(and so on)
```

Thanks for your time and work!

I have posted this also here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/d9km7y/scraping_data_using_bs4_gives_me_unexpected/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrape and write the results in a csv file in few different ways. The one I prefer to go with is pandas. Try using ***[:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)*** in the first place to filter out the unwanted content. That said the following should work:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_URL = 'https://www.youpriboo.com/vorher_102_main_nat.php?action=show&liga='
liga = '2.BL'

URL = f"{base_URL}{liga}"

page = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name_One','Name_Ano','Wahr'])
for tr in soup.select('.prognose_tab_1 tr:has(.greycell)'):
    name1 = tr.select('.hac')[1].get_text()
    name2 = tr.select('.hac')[2].get_text()
    wahr1 = tr.select('.greycell')[0].get_text()
    df = df.append({'Name_One':name1, 'Name_Ano':name2, 'Wahr':wahr1}, ignore_index=True)

    print(f"{name1} {name2} {wahr1}")

df.to_csv("youpriboo.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: wow! thats amazing! thank you very much! now i have to figure out why it is working :D

Comment: Hi Sim, i am still figuring out what is going on. I ve tried to pick the numbers Über and Unter, but the problem is they dont have a class like .hac or .greycell they are just <td>53,94</td>.I ve tried `unter = tr.select('.td')` but it tells me "out of range".
I want this information right after the the other information. Can you tell me how to grap it please.
`Team1 Team2 1 0 X unter über`

Comment: You can get them by using `unter = tr.select('td')[-4].get_text()` and `uber = tr.select('td')[-3].get_text()`. Btw, if you wanna get some more fields or bring about any change, make sure to ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: oh man, it was just that dot that screwed my selector. i've to learn a lot... thank you very much, again!

Answer (score 0):

The filtering is not correct. Try this approach,

```
table = soup.find_all("tr")
#print(table)
for row in table:
    data = row.find_all("td", class_="hac")
    if(len(data)>0):
        print(data[1].get_text(),data[2].get_text())

    data = row.find_all("td", class_="greycell")
    if(len(data)>0):
        print(data[0].get_text())
```

Comment: nice! thank you. but can i get the data printed from greycell after the teams, like in my example?

Comment: If you want all the data from graycell, simply print data. The index is used to identify the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.This will gives you your expected output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_URL = 'https://www.youpriboo.com/vorher_102_main_nat.php?action=show&liga='
liga = '2.BL'
URL = base_URL + liga

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36:'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table=soup.select_one(".prognose_tab_1")
for tr in table.select('tr'):
  if tr.select('.hac') and tr.select('.greycell'):
     name1=tr.select('.hac')[1]
     name2 = tr.select('.hac')[2]
     wahr1 = tr.select('.greycell')[0]

     print(name1.get_text() +' '+ name2.get_text()+' '+ wahr1.get_text())
```

**Output**

```
Arminia Bielefeld VfB Stuttgart 34,43
SV Wehen Wiesbaden VfL Osnabrück 34,51
Jahn Regensburg Hamburger SV 24,18
Karlsruher SC 1. FC Heidenheim 37,70
VfL Bochum SV Darmstadt 98 55,22
Erzgebirge Aue Dynamo Dresden 37,70
FC St. Pauli SV Sandhausen 43,90
SpVgg Greuther Fürth Holstein Kiel 46,23
Hannover 96 1. FC Nürnberg 46,23
```

Comment: thanks, but there is problem
```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```
it says "unexpected indent"

Comment: @Siggi : can you try now.

Comment: nice! Thank you very much! Is there an easy way to put the output into excel or .CSV?

Comment: Yes you can.If you use pandas data frame which is much easier to put data into CSV